# How to include jQuery in my manifest.json file for a chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have read many answers on here, but none of the solutions have worked. I know I am doing something wrong, so I would be very grateful if somebody had the time to help me here.

File-name for my JS-file is main.js

My relevant HTML-Code:

```
<script src="js/main.js" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My entire manifest.json:

```
"name": "Roasts Tab",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "A fire roast every time you open a new tab in Chrome",
"version": "0.0.0.1",
"permissions": ["management"],
"chrome_url_overrides": {
"newtab": "index.html"
 },
 "icons": {
 "128": "icon.png"
 }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two src attributes on your first script tag... It looks like you need to remove the `src="jquery.js"` one, since you're loading jQuery from the cdn.

Also move your own script tag below the jQuery cdn script tag. As it is now, it runs your scripts first, and then loads jQuery after, so your scripts do not have access to the jQuery functions.